# button onclick inside recyclerview notify data set changed isn't updating my view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

So i have a recyclerview with a imagebutton inside, what i am trying to figure out here is how can i notify the recyclerview to update when i click on the imagebutton.

Background: Imagebutton OnClick will add a point and the point TextView will update. Something like reddit point system.

Here is my codes, any aid will be fantastic.

```
public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView mRVProfile;
private com.example.admin.quoteme.AdapterProfile mAdapter;

private android.widget.LinearLayout llLayout;

@Override
public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}


@Override
public android.view.View onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater inflater, android.view.ViewGroup container, android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    android.view.View view = inflater.inflate(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.layout.fragmentglobalfeed, null);
    java.util.List<Profile> data = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

    //recyclerview
    new com.example.admin.quoteme.FragmentGlobalfeed.AsyncFeed().execute("feed");

    return view;


}

public class AsyncFeed extends android.os.AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    java.net.HttpURLConnection conn;
    java.net.URL url = null;

    String quote_url = "http://192.168.0.100/Quoteme/quotepointV2.php";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("feed")) {
            try {
                //enter url address where ur json file is
                url = new java.net.URL("http://192.168.0.100/Quoteme/updated_getfeed.php");
            } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {
                conn = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
            } catch (java.io.IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try {
                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                if (response_code == java.net.HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    //read data
                    java.io.InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    return (result.toString());
                } else {

                    return ("unsuccessful");
                }
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        } else if (method.equals("quotepoint")) {
            try {

                String quoteid, userid;
                quoteid = params[1];
                userid = params[2];
                java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(quote_url);
                java.net.HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                java.io.OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                java.io.BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new java.io.BufferedWriter(new java.io.OutputStreamWriter((outputStream), "UTF-8"));

                String data = java.net.URLEncoder.encode("quoteid", "UTF-8") + "=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(quoteid, "UTF-8")
                        + "&" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode("userid", "UTF-8") + "=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(userid, "UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                java.io.InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                java.io.BufferedReader bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append((line + "\n"));
                }
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

            } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.net.ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return method;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        java.util.List<Profile> data = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
        try {
            org.json.JSONArray jArray = new org.json.JSONArray(result);
            //extraction
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                org.json.JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Profile profile = new Profile();
                profile.setUser_id(json_data.getString("username"));
                profile.setQuote_points(json_data.getInt("quote_points"));
                profile.setQuote(json_data.getString("quote_description"));
                data.add(profile);
            }

            //setup and hand data over to rv // adapter
            mRVProfile = (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.recyclerViewGlobal);
            mAdapter = new AdapterProfile(getActivity(), data);
            mRVProfile.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mRVProfile.setLayoutManager(new android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
            //android.widget.Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.toString(), android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

    }
}
```

you can see i throw mAdapter.notify in onPostExecute method like many has advocated, but still no luck. I have to physically refresh the recyclerview by the means of having it generate the view all over again to see the result change.

And here is my adapter.

```
private android.content.Context context;
private android.view.LayoutInflater inflater;
java.util.List<Profile> data = java.util.Collections.emptyList();

public AdapterProfile(android.content.Context context, java.util.List<com.example.admin.quoteme.Profile> data){

    this.context=context;
    inflater= android.view.LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

@Override
public android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

    android.view.View view = inflater.inflate(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.layout.feed_layout_v2, parent, false);
    MyHolder holder = new com.example.admin.quoteme.AdapterProfile.MyHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
    MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
    com.example.admin.quoteme.Profile current=data.get(position);
    myHolder.name.setText(current.getUser_id());
    myHolder.quote.setText(current.getQuote());
    myHolder.points.setText(current.getQuote_points() + " Points");


    // load image into imageview using glide
    /*Glide.with(context).load("http://192.168.1.7/test/images/" + current.fishImage)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
            .into(myHolder.ivFish);*/
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    private android.widget.TextView name,quote,points,comment;
    private android.widget.ImageButton btnPoints;

    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(android.view.View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (android.widget.TextView)itemView.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.name);
        quote = (android.widget.TextView)itemView.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.quote);
        points = (android.widget.TextView)itemView.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.points);
        comment = (android.widget.TextView)itemView.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.tvComment);
        btnPoints = (android.widget.ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.imageButton1);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        comment.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPoints.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(android.view.View v) {

        android.content.SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.string.PREF_FILE), android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        final String userid = sharedPreferences.getString(context.getString(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.string.USER_ID), "");



        if (v.getId() == btnPoints.getId()){
            //String quoteid = String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition());
            android.widget.Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ITEM PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(context);
            //backgroundTask.execute("quotepoint", String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition() + 1 ) + "", userid);

            FragmentGlobalfeed fragmentGlobalfeed = new FragmentGlobalfeed();
            fragmentGlobalfeed.new AsyncFeed().execute("quotepoint", String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition() + 1 ) + "", userid);



        }
        else {
            android.widget.Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "ROW PRESSED = " + String.valueOf(getAdapterPosition()), android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here in my adapter class, inside myHolder class, there is onClicks handling the process. Should the mAdapter.notify be located in the onClick? I thought of it, but i am unable to do it because there isn't any declaration of mAdapter, it was declared in FragmentGlobalFeed class.

What should i do here? Thanks for your time.

Comment: send updated data to adapter when new data load. in your case you are calling notifydatasetchange but your are  not sending updated data to adapter

Comment: what the button does is trigger asynctask and then follows php mysql methods, the updated values is all inside mysql. Do i do another retrieval? Why can't i utilise the retrieval i did earlier?

Answer (score 0):

```
 data.add(new Profile());
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(data.size()-1);
```

Comment: hi thanks for your effort, but that isn't what i am looking for. i am not deleting nor inserting any new data, i just want to refresh the recyclerview so the new data will be shown.